# How do I run a jar file with QProcess

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qprocess

I have been running batch files that run jar files before.

The contents of my batch file are:

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8 -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m C:\val\val.jar --basedir C:\val --filetype shp --cidx 5 --layerdefpath C:\val\임상도layer.json --valoptpath C:\val\임상도option.json --objfilepath C:\val\50000.zip --crs EPSG:5186

pause>nul
```

And in my Python I did this.

```
query = 'C:/val/start.bat'
# self.process is mean QProcess()
self.process.start(query)
```

And these have been done successfully.

Now, I want to call the jar file directly instead of the batch file.

My new code is:

```
program = os.path.join(os.environ["JAVA_HOME"], r"bin\java.exe")

self.process.start(program,
                   ['-Dfile.encoding=utf-8', '-Djava.file.encoding=UTF-8', '-jar',
                    '-Xms1024m', '-Xmx1024m', r'C:\val\val.jar',
                    # args
                    r'--basedir', r'C:\val',
                    r'--filetype', 'shp',
                    r'--cidx', r'%s' % str(self.dockwidget.cidx.currentIndex() + 1),
                    r'--layerdefpath', r'%s' % self.dockwidget.path1.text().replace("/", "\\", 2).decode('utf-8'),
                    r'--valoptpath', r'%s' % self.dockwidget.path2.text().replace("/", "\\", 2).decode('utf-8'),
                    r'--objfilepath', r'%s' % self.dockwidget.path3.text().replace("/", "\\", 2).decode('utf-8'),
                    r'--crs', 'EPSG:5186'])
```

But this does not work.

Note that all parameter information is the same. (Backspace is also the same.
 There is no difference in the letters. )

Could you tell me how to run it normally?

Comment: I tested it, but java -version also does not work.

Comment: Could you `print(os.environ["JAVA_HOME"])`?